# Validacion registro duplicado en formulario con Javascript

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación

Tengo un un formulario en Javascript que hace un Post a una tabla para generar una factura de productos todo lo hace de maravilla.

Requiero validar que uno de mis datos ( el código del producto ) no se encuentre ya en mis datos para evitar que se dupliquen registros al generar la factura.

¿Podrían ayudarme?

Aqui el Codigo de el formulario:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        load(1);
    });

    function load(page){
        var q= $("#q").val();
        $("#loader").fadeIn('slow');
        $.ajax({
            url:'./ajax/productos_factura.php?action=ajax&page='+page+'&q='+q,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
             $('#loader').html('<img src="./img/ajax-loader.gif"> Cargando...');
          },
            success:function(data){
                $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                $('#loader').html('');

            }
        })
    }

function agregar (id)
    {
        var precio_venta=document.getElementById('precio_venta_'+id).value;
        var cantidad=document.getElementById('cantidad_'+id).value;
        //Inicia validacion
        if (isNaN(cantidad))
        {
        alert('Esto no es un numero');
        document.getElementById('cantidad_'+id).focus();
        return false;
        }
        if (isNaN(precio_venta))
        {
        alert('Esto no es un numero');
        document.getElementById('precio_venta_'+id).focus();
        return false;
        }
        //Fin validacion

        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./ajax/agregar_facturacion.php",
    data: "id="+id+"&precio_venta="+precio_venta+"&cantidad="+cantidad,
     beforeSend: function(objeto){
        $("#resultados").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
      },
    success: function(datos){
    $("#resultados").html(datos);
    }
        });
    }

        function eliminar (id)
    {

        $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "./ajax/agregar_facturacion.php",
    data: "id="+id,
     beforeSend: function(objeto){
        $("#resultados").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
      },
    success: function(datos){
    $("#resultados").html(datos);
    }
        });

    }

    $("#datos_factura").submit(function(){
      var id_cliente = $("#id_cliente").val();
      var id_vendedor = $("#id_vendedor").val();
      var condiciones = $("#condiciones").val();

      if (id_cliente==""){
          alert("Debes seleccionar un cliente");
          $("#nombre_cliente").focus();
          return false;
      }
     VentanaCentrada('./pdf/documentos/factura_pdf.php?id_cliente='+id_cliente+'&id_vendedor='+id_vendedor+'&condiciones='+condiciones,'Factura','','1024','768','true');
    });

    $( "#guardar_cliente" ).submit(function( event ) {
      $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

     var parametros = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/nuevo_cliente.php",
                data: parametros,
                 beforeSend: function(objeto){
                    $("#resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
                  },
                success: function(datos){
                $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
                $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
                load(1);
              }
        });
      event.preventDefault();
    })

    $( "#guardar_producto" ).submit(function( event ) {
      $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

     var parametros = $(this).serialize();
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/nuevo_producto.php",
                data: parametros,
                 beforeSend: function(objeto){
                    $("#resultados_ajax_productos").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
                  },
                success: function(datos){
                $("#resultados_ajax_productos").html(datos);
                $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
                load(1);
              }
        });
      event.preventDefault();
    })
```

Los datos los tomo de este archivo en Ajax:

```
    <?php
include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
/* Connect To Database*/
require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
if($action == 'ajax'){
    // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
     $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
     $aColumns = array('codigo_producto', 'nombre_producto');//Columnas de busqueda
     $sTable = "products";
     $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$q."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
    include 'pagination.php'; //incluyo archivo de paginacion
    //variables de paginacion
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
    $per_page = 5; //cuantoas regis
    $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    //Count the total number of row in your table*/
    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
    $numrows = $row['numrows'];
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
    $reload = './index.php';
    //main query to fetch the data
    $sql="SELECT * FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    //loop through fetched data
    if ($numrows>0){

        ?>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <tr  class="warning">
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th><span class="pull-right">Cant.</span></th>
                <th><span class="pull-right">Precio</span></th>
                <th class='text-center' style="width: 36px;">Agregar</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $id_producto=$row['id_producto'];
                $codigo_producto=$row['codigo_producto'];
                $nombre_producto=$row['nombre_producto'];
                $precio_venta=$row["precio_producto"];
                $precio_venta=number_format($precio_venta,2,'.','');
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $codigo_producto; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $nombre_producto; ?></td>
                    <td class='col-xs-1'>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" id="cantidad_<?php echo $id_producto; ?>"  value="1" >
                    </div></td>
                    <td class='col-xs-2'><div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" id="precio_venta_<?php echo $id_producto; ?>"  value="<?php echo $precio_venta;?>" >
                    </div></td>
                    <td class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-info'href="#" onclick="agregar('<?php echo $id_producto ?>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=5><span class="pull-right">
                <?php
                 echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents);
                ?></span></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: ¿Tus datos, donde se encuentran guardados?

Comment: Los Datos de origen viene de una tabla que se llama "productos" y luego por medio de ajax hago el post y esa info se guarda en otra tabla que se llama "facturas".

Comment: Mi duda es si puedo hacer una validación del tipo " mysql.num.rows > 0 " pero antes de hacer el post con una alerta así como tengo las validaciones numéricas. No se si me de entender... o si es posible.

Comment: ¿Pero los datos de la BBDD los sacas con PHP? ¿Como haces la query? ¿Podrias poner esa parte tambien please? Tengo un par de respuestas, pero no me decido por cual.

Comment: Lo quieres validar al ingresarlo a la base de datos? podrias poner un indice en la base de datos indicando que es UNIQUE

Comment: si lo puedes hacer el dilema es donde quieres que valide en el front o en el back si es en el front debes hacer un servicio de consulta y si es en el back tambien debes manejar los variables en la session en ambos caso necesitamos el codigo

Comment: @JackNavaRow eso es lo que estoy esperando a que responda! Si es back como consigue los datos?? query php, un procedimiento almacenado,... si es front es totalme diferente. Y no voy a postear todas las respuestas posibles jajaja

Comment: El back y el front **trabajan juntos siempre** y para eso existen recursos para que exista una comunicación. Para saber si el código ya existe o no realiza una consulta por AJAX al backend y actúa de acuerdo a la respuesta.

Comment: Disculpen la tardanza, acá en mi pueblo desde el temblor de hace un mes la luz y por consiguiente el Internet son bastante erráticos. Ya coloque el codigo de mi formulario y el de el ajax.

Comment: Te la pondre facil, en la tabla de productos haz lo siguiente: en el codigo de producto puedes colocar un indice donde el codigo de producto debe ser unique

Comment: Si de hecho fue en lo primero que pensé pero la tabla así lo tengo como Unique, el formulario no guarda la informacion en la tabla de productos, la guarda en la tabla de Facturas y es en la factura donde quiero que no se pueda duplicar el código ( ya que en productos ya lo tengo ) mi intención es que si quiero meter 2 productos iguales me arroje un mensaje de error indicando que el producto esta duplicado.

De antemano muchas gracias Bro.